# Value not updating in QML when set through an 'animated' property

Tags: android, c++, qt, qml

**Platform:** Android

**Preliminaries:**

Basically, there's a text-field whose value is updated from C++.

The text-field has a public string property (*valueStr*), which is data-bound to the 'native' text property.

```
TextField
{
 id:valueTxt
 property string valueStr:""
 text: valueStr
   Behavior on valueStr {
    FadeAnimation {
     target: valueTxt
      }
  }
}
```

The reason is to animate the text-field whenever its value changes. Which is why I introduce the public property (*valueStr*), so the Behaviour is supposed to trigger each and every time the property *valueStr* gets updated and nicely 'animate' the 'native' text property, as perceived by user.

The FadeAnimation QML module is defined as follows:

```
//FadeAnimation.qml
import QtQuick 2.0

SequentialAnimation {
    id: root
    property QtObject target
    property string fadeProperty: "scale"
    property int fadeDuration: 150
    property alias outValue: outAnimation.to
    property alias inValue: inAnimation.to
    property alias outEasingType: outAnimation.easing.type
    property alias inEasingType: inAnimation.easing.type
    property string easingType: "Quad"
    NumberAnimation { // in the default case, fade scale to 0
        id: outAnimation
        target: root.target
        property: root.fadeProperty
        duration: root.fadeDuration
        to: 0
        easing.type: Easing["In"+root.easingType]
    }
    PropertyAction { } // actually change the property targeted by the Behavior between the 2 other animations
    NumberAnimation { // in the default case, fade scale back to 1
        id: inAnimation
        target: root.target
        property: root.fadeProperty
        duration: root.fadeDuration
        to: 1
        easing.type: Easing["Out"+root.easingType]
    }
}
```

**The Problem:**
Whether the text-field value actually updates seems to be random.
Sometimes it animates to a previous value, other times it animated to a new one.
I'm wondering whether it's a bug, or whether I'm doing something wrong. (seems like a BUG?)
If I remove animation and update the text property directly, new value is shown each time, as expected.

**What's been verified:**
The valueStr **is** each and every time set to the expected value.
It's just the animation which seems to be causing trouble.

Comment: What version of Qt are you using? I tried it out by using a timer to update valueStr and it seemed to work fine. I'm on 5.15.7.

Comment: 'latest' publicly available from the 5.* branch i..e through the installer 5.15.2 .. where did you get 5.15.7 from ;-) by the way; have you tried on Android? I mean it worked for us too quite well but then turned out to be very problematic

Comment: The latest right now is actually [5.15.8](https://www.qt.io/blog/commercial-lts-qt-5.15.8-released). I'm testing on Linux.

Comment: Seems like QT has separate distribution channels for OpenSource and Commercial licenses, we're on latest OpenSource version as seen by the installer; also no intentions of building Qt from source each time it pops out. Had no idea QT makes Open Source users lag behind.